Always search node_modules when looking for file in Visual Studio Code
On macOS, when searching for a project file in Visual Studio Code using Cmd + P, I want node_modules included among the searchable files every time I search.
How to permanently enable this?

The top-voted answer on the other quesiton gives a temporary solution, but the question is not about doing this temporarily. This remains a duplicate question. Feel free to post your answer over there if you think you have a unique answer.

This is not a duplicate. The original question does not ask (a) "how to ALWAYS search node modules" (this is my question). It asks (b) "how to search node modules" without explicitly stating ALWAYS or TEMPORARY. However the top answer for (b) gives a TEMPORARY solution. That does not help me. That's why I wrote this post. To help others seeking a permanent fix.  @chris

Questions on Stack Overflow can have multiple answers. Many do, including the duplicate one here. This answer on the duplicate gives the same answer that you have provided below. If the other question explicitly asked how to do this temporarily I might agree, but it doesn't. It asks how to do it, leaving the door open for both temporary and permanent solutions. It's a dupe.

Questions closed as dupes aren't automatically bad questions. Good dupes can remain open and act as signposts to canonical questions with more (and often better) answers. I'm voting to re-close this as a duplicate. This question is included in the scope of the other question, and an answer over there is the same as the answer shown below.

The “answer over there” is not the accepted solution. If it was one part of the accepted solution, I would agree. The other question is a non-specific question with a specific answer. This post is a specific question with a specific answer. They two questions are not equivalent. Nor are the answers. Why make people search through all answers of a general question, when an explicit question and answer more quickly solves their problem? This wastes people’s time.

It doesn't have to be the accepted solution for this to be a duplicate question. Please consider retaking the [tour], which clearly explains that "Good answers are voted up and rise to the top. The best answers show up first so that they are always easy to find." / "The person who asked can mark one answer as 'accepted'. Accepting doesn't mean it's the best answer, it just means that it worked for the person who asked."

On mac

Open settings

cmd + ,
or navigate via code → settings → settings


Type search.exclude
Delete **/node_modules from Search: Exclude



Type .gitignore
Under features → search
Deselect "Controls whether to use .gitignore and .ignore files when searching


node_modules should be immediately searchable. If not, restart VSC.
